# How display actual syntax highlight in vim?

Tags: vim, makefile, syntax-highlighting, gnu-make, file-type

Recently I wrote a text file without a file extension with the vim text editor and got text highlightning for all words between singel quotes like `'word'` and all words ending with a colon like `word:`

I like this kind of highlightning.

But because I havent typed any command, which usually starts with `ESC` `:command`, I was surprised how this could happen.

Is there a command to display the actual syntax highlight which is in use?

I already have tried the command `:set syntax=php` which seems simliar only with different color for words like `word:`

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: you want to know the syntax? or what to know the "hi" information of  highlighted text?

Comment: The issue derived from highlightning files without an extension. For that I wanted to know which case of syntax vim detected. As I mentioned below im my comment vim detects more `makefile`'s than suggestet by `man make`. zaraks answer `:echo &syntax` gave me the hint.

Comment: Try `:verb set ft`.  Much more useful information.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/686241/how-do-i-tell-what-syntax-file-is-being-used

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try entering the command

```
:echo &syntax
```

This will display the value that the `syntax` variable has been set to.

Comment: This works, thank you. It echoed syntax highlight for `make` but it isn't a make file. Its just named 'how_to_makefile' but this seems to be another problem/question.

Comment: It seems that vim takes evere file named `textstring_makefile` or `makefile_textstring` as a makefile.

Comment: You're right - vim inspects the name of the file to determine the filetype, which can be used to set the syntax variable. You can read more about it [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html).

Comment: Yes, I have already read this page. But haven't find any information. If I execute in vim `:filetype detection` vim prints no information neither the file has an extenion. I've tried several file names, but it seems that the variants in my previous comment let vim detect a `makefile` that is not recommended by `man make`.

Answer (score 5):

```
set option=value "set the option with value
set option?      "read/print the current value of the option
set option!      "set the option with opposite value, like set nu and set nu!
```

the option value is also saved in variable `&option` so you can read in script way.